# postgresql thread safety for temporary tables

Tags: java, postgresql

This the syntax I use for creating a temporary table:

```
create temp table tmpTable (id bigint not null, primary key (id)) on commit drop;
```

I know this means that at the end of each transaction, this table will be dropped. 
My question is, if two or more threads on the same session create and insert values into a temporary table, will they each get their own instance or is the temporary instance shared across the session? If it's shared, is there a way to make it local per thread?

Thanks
Netta

Comment: Are they sharing one DB connection, or does each thread have its own?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Temporary tables are visible to all operations in the same session. So you **cannot** create a temporary table of the same name **in the same session** before you drop the one that exists (commit the transaction in your case).

You may want to use:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmptbl IF NOT EXISTS ...
```

[More about `CREATE TABLE` in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html)

---

#### Unique temp tables

To make the temp table local per "thread" (in the same session) you need to use **unique table names**. One way would be to use an unbound `SEQUENCE` and dynamic SQL - in a procedural language like plpgsql or in a DO statement (which is basically the same without storing a function.

Run one:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE myseq;
```

Use:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE tmp' || nextval('myseq')  ||'(id int)';
END;
$$
```

To know the latest table name:

```
SELECT 'tmp' || currval('myseq');
```

Or put it all into a plpgsql function and return the table or reuse the table name.

All further SQL commands have to be executed dynamically, though, as plain SQL statements operate with hard coded identifiers. So, it is probably best, to put it all into a plpgsql function.

---

#### Unique ID to use same temp table

Another possible solution could be to use the **same temp table** for all threads in the same session and add a column **`thread_id`** to the table. Be sure to index the column, if you make heavy use of the feature. Then use a unique `thread_id` per thread (in the same session).

Once only:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE myseq;
```

Once per thread:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmptbl(thread_id int, col1 int) IF NOT EXISTS;
my_id :=  nextval('myseq'); -- in plpgsql
-- else find another way to assign unique id per thread
```

SQL:

```
INSERT INTO tmptbl(thread_id, col1) VALUES
(my_id, 2), (my_id, 3), (my_id, 4);

SELECT * FROM tmptbl WHERE thread_id = my_id;
```

Comment: The whole point is that I need different temp tables per thread. Is there no way to create a local temp table?

Comment: @netta: Temporary tables are *local* to the session. Use separate sessions if you want to operate with identical names. Else you have to resort to dynamic SQL like I added to my answer. Or use a unique ID per thread - I added another idea to my answer.

Comment: This is as elegant as it can get in PostgreSQL. Nicely done, sir.

Comment: If a temp table is marked WITH ON COMMIT DROP, how will PG handle multiple threads accessing that table? Any thread could commit, but the table couldn't be dropped as it's in use.

Comment: @IamIC: Only one transaction at a time can run within the same session. So this situation is not possible. Theoretically this could be changed (AFAIC), but that's how it's implemented.