# Get result from query in DO satement

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.1, plpgsql

How to run SQL statement within an IF condition in plpgsql? I don't want to create or replace a function. This is what I tried:

```
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$
BEGIN
IF 'Khosla' = 'Khosla' THEN
SELECT * FROM test_log limit 10;
ELSE
RAISE NOTICE 'not worked';
END IF;
END;
$$;

ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "inline_code_block" line 3 at SQL statement
```

I also tried this but was unable to get data:

```
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$
BEGIN
if 'a' = 'a' THEN
PERFORM * FROM test_log limit 10;
else
raise notice 'not worked';
end if;
end;
$$;

Output: Query returned successfully with no result in 13 ms.
```

After reading document properly I came to know that PERFORM executes SQL and discards result set.

Can you help in running the SQL Statement and getting the result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *cannot* return values from a `DO` statement. Create a plpgsql function instead.

There are several ways to define the return type with the `RETURNING` clause or with `OUT` parameters. Read the manual about [`CREATE FUNCTION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html).

There are several ways to return values from the function. Read the chapter [Returning From a Function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) in the manual.

In particular, since you are trying to return whole rows from a table, you can use the registered type of the table for the function declaration:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo ()
  RETURNING SETOF test_log 
$func$
BEGIN

IF 'a' = 'a' THEN
  RETURN QUERY
  SELECT * FROM test_log LIMIT 10;
ELSE
   RAISE WARNING $$Didn't work!$$;
END IF;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM foo ();
```

Or try a search here on SO. I posted [many related code examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:939860%20%5Bplpgsql%5D%20%5Bpostgresql%5D%20returning%20from%20function).

#### Workaround for `DO` statement

If you cannot use a function, the only halfway sensible workaround with a DO statement is to use a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tbl_tmp AS
SELECT * FROM test_log LIMIT 0;

$do$
BEGIN

IF 'a' = 'a' THEN
  INSERT INTO tbl_tmp
  SELECT * FROM test_log LIMIT 10;
ELSE
   RAISE WARNING $$Didn't work!$$;
END IF;

END
$do$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM tbl_tmp;
```

[Temporary tables are dropped automatically at the end of the session.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873735/select-from-a-table-variable/17873935#17873935)

Comment: Please find my answer and also comment. Thanks you very much

Comment: Hey can you provide me any links/references about this Temporary table concept.This will help me future in lot.

Comment: @Naveen: There's a link at the end of my answer. [Here's another.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596896/postgresql-thread-safety-for-temporary-tables/10598224#10598224). There are more related answers, try a search.

Comment: Thanks @Erwin Brandstetter

Answer (score 0):

**Finally I Did IT - Passing Parameter in plpgsql function.**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION param_test_1(text)
RETURNS TABLE (comp_id int, comp_name text, comp_sort text) AS $$
BEGIN
IF 'company' = $1 THEN
RETURN QUERY SELECT id::int as comp_id, ltrim(company.compname)::text as compname, ltrim(company.compname)::text as sort FROM company where deleteflag = '0' and active = '1' and id in (270,394,376,396,403);
ELSEIF 'jobs' = $1 THEN
RAISE NOTICE 'Not Working';
END IF;
RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM param_test_1('company');
```

This is working perfectly. Any suggestions for better approach on my work will be highly appreciated. Thanks