# Quoted NULL values makes PostgreSQL COPY command fail

Tags: postgresql, csv, null, postgresql-copy

I have a big CSV file with all columns quoted with `"`.
Null values are represented as `""`, and column separator is `|`.
I would like to use the [`COPY`command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-copy.html) from postgresql (version 10.7) to ingest those files.
I have tried many combination, but the more natural to me is the following:

```
COPY test.large
FROM '/path/to/big.file'
WITH (
    FORMAT CSV,
    HEADER,
    DELIMITER '|',
    QUOTE '"',
    NULL ''
);
```

My underlying table expects a column for integers and there are lines where `NULL` value are set to `...|""|...` instead of some number `...|"123456"|...`. And unfortunately, this makes `COPY` to crash, saying:

```
ERREUR:  syntaxe en entrée invalide pour l'entier : «  »
CONTEXT:  COPY regpat_pct_app_reg, ligne 2743, colonne appid : «  »
```

Sorry, it is in French from this terminal. Anyway, it says:  `Invalid syntax for integer : «  »`
At the line 2743 we found:

```
...000205"|""|"XY...
```

Which is a `NULL` value, but I cannot found how to properly setup `COPY` command switch to make postgresql ingest those files.

The documentation says:

> `NULL`
>
> Specifies the string that represents a null value. The default is \N (backslash-N) in text format, and an unquoted empty string in
>   CSV format. You might prefer an empty string even in text format for
>   cases where you don't want to distinguish nulls from empty strings.
>   This option is not allowed when using binary format.

I am aware that I can clean the file by changing `...|""|...` to `...||...` using `sed` or some regexp/replace operations. This will solve my problem, I have checked it.

What I am wondering: is it possible to bear it with postgresql, after all this is perfectly valid CSV format.

**Update**

Reading the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56393289/3067485) as suggested, I wrote:

```
COPY test.large
FROM '/path/to/big.file'
WITH (
        FORMAT CSV,
        HEADER,
        DELIMITER '|',
        QUOTE '"',
        NULL '',
        FORCE_NULL appid
    );
```

I get:

```
ERREUR:  l'argument de l'option « force_null » doit être une liste de noms de colonnes
```

Which translates to `force_null must be a list of column names`. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it is a slight inconsistency in the `COPY` command switches, because the following call:

```
COPY test.large
FROM '/path/to/big.file'
WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER '|' QUOTE '"' FORCE NULL appid;
```

Works as expected or you must add the `_` if you use the key value pair notation:

```
COPY test.large
FROM '/path/to/big.file'
WITH (
    FORMAT CSV,
    HEADER,
    DELIMITER '|',
    QUOTE '"',
    FORCE_NULL (appln_id)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't NULL, it's an empty string which is a different thing. I'm not aware of a way to make PG treat an empty string as a null number. I recommend you do your import to a temporary table with a text column instead of an integer here, then move the data to the main table converting to number as appropriate

Take a look at this Q: [Postgresql COPY empty string as NULL not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45892420/postgresql-copy-empty-string-as-null-not-work)

Very similar to your scenario and the accepted answer there describes a similar technique

Comment: I agree and you'd maybe think that by telling OG that quote is '"' and null is '' that it will first remove the quotes from `,"",...` and find nothing inside them and then understand that it's the same as your null spec ''.. but it doesn't; it find empty string. If you'd said `quote '"' null 'nul'` and your csv was like `...,"nul",nul,...` you might think that they're both null, but one is SQL NULL as per spec and one is a string literal of `nul`. Does it make sense? Think of it like "it looks for null before it removes quotes, not after it removes quotes"

Comment: I have tried something suggested in your reference. I have updated my post to reflect the error. Funny it requires a list of column names.

Comment: @jlandercy: you need to use `FORCE_NULL (appid)` (i.e a 1-element list).

Comment: Unfortunetley it does not work, but I have found a solution: `erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « NULL »
LINE 9:         FORCE NULL (appid)
                      ^`

Comment: @jlandercy: just to make sure, do you have an underscore between `FORCE` and `NULL`?

Comment: Ok I have found why we have this `_` or not discussion, see my answer. Thank you for taking time to solve my problem.